# Why does an integer index inside a symbol become real when entering a ChebyshevT function with floating point arithmetic?

Tags: special-functions, number-representation

When I enter an indexed symbol into a ChebyshevT function with integer arithmetic like this:

```
ChebyshevT[1, 3 * a[4]]
```

I get the expected result:

```
3 a[4]
```

But when I use floating point arithmetic within it:

```
ChebyshevT[1, 3. * a[4]]
```

I quite surprisingly get:

```
3. a[4.]
```

instead of expected:

```
3. a[4]
```

what's happening there? Why did the index inside the symbol change at all??
This is not happening with other mathematical fuctions like Sin, Cos, etc.

Thank you in advance for your help, regards,

Comment: Indeed, this seems weird and inconsistent. The same thing happens in `ChebyshevT`, `ChebyshevU`, `Gamma`, `LegendreP`, `HermiteH`, `GegenbauerC` ... but not in `JacobiSN`, `BesselJ`, `ExpIntegralE` ... Perhaps you should report it to [Wolfram Technical Support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/?topic=feedback).

Comment: That certainly looks like a bug.

Comment: You may be able to work around the issue by doing `SetAttributes[a, NHoldAll]`.

Comment: As for "consistency," the buggy results are for special functions evaluating to elementary functions.  And it does happen for the Bessel function `BesselJ[1/2, 3.*a[4]]`.

Comment: Thank you everybody for your help. I have just reported the issue to Wolfram Technical Support. I will let you know the answer as they reply me...

Comment: "Hello Danel,
Thank you for taking the time to send your report.
It does appear that ChebyshevT is not behaving properly. I have forwarded an issue report to our developers with the information you provided, and added your contact information to the report so that you can be notified when it is resolved.
We are always interested in improving Mathematica, and I want to thank you once again for bringing this issue to our attention. If you run into any other problems with any of our products or have any additional questions, please do not hesitate to contact us."